# ng-repeat not getting updated on model change

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to update list on model change, but some times the ng-repeat works and sometimes it doesnt, can someone help me as in why this is hapenning
I am calling angular function from jQuery the code is:

```
angular.element($('#updateGroupPannel')).scope().prepareToUpdate(group);
```

This is the angular function being called and the angular code:

```
$scope.prepareToUpdate = function(group)
{
    $scope.groupId = group.id;
    $scope.usersPageChanged();
    $scope.adminsExistingPageChanged();
}
$scope.usersPageChanged = function()
{
    workbenchService.usersUnderAdminList($scope.currentUserPage).then(function(data)
    {
        $scope.usersExisting = data;
    })
};
$scope.adminsExistingPageChanged = function()
{
    workbenchService.groupAdminsList($scope.currentExistingAdminPage, $scope.groupId).then(function(data)
    {
        $scope.editGroup.admins = data;
    })
};
```

This is the html code which populates the list of users and admins:

```
<form name="GroupUpdate" id="updateGroupPannel" ng-controller="updateController">
    <div ng-repeat="user in editGroup.appUsers track by $index">
       <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div>{{user.name}}</div>
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="admin in editGroup.admins track by $index">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div>{{admin.name}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The problem is sometimes the ng-repeat gets updated for $scope.usersExisting but sometimes it doesnt get updated, any help is highly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Before continuing, why you are you calling an Angular function from jQuery? There are very few cases where you actually have to do this.

Comment: I am working on a project where jsTree plugin is used so I have no option but to call angular from jquery when the node of tree is selected . . is there a better way to achieve this please let me kno, thanks for the reply

Comment: You may need native angular tree implementation. I have one and can share it with you. It gets full json as input and displays tree structure of checkboxes. The value of control is an array if IDs of checked values. It also can restore data. If you need it, I can give you code as it is so you customise it for your needs.

Comment: thank u all for ur reply, but I got the solution, and the problem was I was not chaining the promises, once I did that its working perfectly now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the answer as it mite be helpful for someone stuck with same problem, the issue here was the promises were not chained I made the following changes and it is now working perfectly,

```
$scope.prepareToUpdate = function(group)
{
    $scope.groupId = group.id;
    $scope.usersPageChanged().then(function(){
        $scope.adminsExistingPageChanged();
    });
}
$scope.usersPageChanged = function()
{
    var promise = workbenchService.usersUnderAdminList($scope.currentUserPage).then(function(data)
    {
        $scope.usersExisting = data;
    })
    return promise;
};
$scope.adminsExistingPageChanged = function()
{
    var promise = workbenchService.groupAdminsList($scope.currentExistingAdminPage, $scope.groupId).then(function(data)
    {
        $scope.editGroup.admins = data;
    })
    return promise;
};
```